# Adding values to object inside array not working - cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, undefined

I am trying to transform a JSON that was build from a CSV file

```
[
    {
      "id_familia": 15,
      "relacao": 1,
      "occupation": "RESPONSAVEL",
      "parent_id": null,
      "id": 1547,
      "name": "name resp 1",
      "surname": "surname resp 1",
    },
    {
        "id_familia": 15,
        "relacao": 2,
        "occupation": "DEPENDENTE",
        "parent_id": 15,
        "id": 1548,
        "name": "name dep 1",
        "surname": "surname dep 1",
      },
      {
        "id_familia": 15,
        "relacao": 2,
        "occupation": "DEPENDENTE",
        "parent_id": 15,
        "id": 1549,
        "name": "name dep 2",
        "surname": "surname dep 2",
      },
    {
      "id_familia": 20,
      "relacao": 1,
      "occupation": "RESPONSAVEL",
      "parent_id": null,
      "id": 1178,
      "name": "name resp 2",
      "surname": "PAPARELLA",
    },
    {
      "id_familia": 20,
      "relacao": 1,
      "occupation": "CONJUGE",
      "parent_id": 20,
      "id": 2010,
      "name": "name dep 1",
      "surname": "surname dep 1",
    },
    {
      "id_familia": 20,
      "relacao": 2,
      "occupation": "DEPENDENTE",
      "parent_id": 20,
      "id": 1188,
      "name": "name dep 2",
      "surname": "surname dep 2",
    }
  ]
```

I need to create a nested JSON that needs to give the following result:

```
[
  {
    "responsible": {
      "id": "1547",
      "id_familia": 15,
      "name": "name resp 1",
      "surname": "surname resp 1",
    },
    "dependents": [
      {
        "member": {
          "id": "1548",
          "id_familia": 15,
          "name": "name dep 1",
          "surname": "surname dep 1",
          "activities": [],
          "programs": []
        }
      },
      {
        "member": {
          "id": "1549",
          "id_familia": 15,
          "name": "name dep 2",
          "surname": "surname dep 2",
          "activities": [],
          "programs": []
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "responsible": {
      "id": "1178",
      "id_familia": 20,
      "name": "name resp 1",
      "surname": "surname resp 1",
    },
    "dependents": [
      {
        "member": {
          "id": "2010",
          "id_familia": 20,
          "name": "name dep 1",
          "surname": "surname dep 1",
          "activities": [],
          "programs": []
        }
      },
      {
        "member": {
          "id": "1188",
          "id_familia": 20,
          "name": "name dep 2",
          "surname": "surname dep 2",
          "activities": [],
          "programs": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My code is below.

```
const data = [
    {
      "id_familia": 15,
      "relacao": 1,
      "occupation": "RESPONSAVEL",
      "parent_id": null,
      "id": 1547,
      "name": "name resp 1",
      "surname": "surname resp 1",
    },
    {
        "id_familia": 15,
        "relacao": 2,
        "occupation": "DEPENDENTE",
        "parent_id": 15,
        "id": 1548,
        "name": "name dep 1",
        "surname": "surname dep 1",
      },
      {
        "id_familia": 15,
        "relacao": 2,
        "occupation": "DEPENDENTE",
        "parent_id": 15,
        "id": 1548,
        "name": "name dep 2",
        "surname": "surname dep 2",
      },
    {
      "id_familia": 20,
      "relacao": 1,
      "occupation": "RESPONSAVEL",
      "parent_id": null,
      "id": 1178,
      "name": "name resp 2",
      "surname": "PAPARELLA",
    },
    {
      "id_familia": 20,
      "relacao": 1,
      "occupation": "CONJUGE",
      "parent_id": 20,
      "id": 2010,
      "name": "name dep 1",
      "surname": "surname dep 1",
    },
    {
      "id_familia": 20,
      "relacao": 2,
      "occupation": "DEPENDENTE",
      "parent_id": 20,
      "id": 1188,
      "name": "name dep 2",
      "surname": "surname dep 2",
    }
  ]


var data1 = [
    {
        resp:{},
        dependents:[
            {
                member:[],
                programs:[],
                activities:[],
            }
        ],
    },
] 

var respCont = -1
var depCont = 0

for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    const element = data[index];
    if(element[index].occupation == "RESPONSAVEL") {
        respCont++ //adds one to resp index
        memberCont = 0
        data1[respCont].resp = {
            id: element.id,
            id_familia: element.id_familia,
            name: element.name,
            surname: element.surname,
        }
    } else {
        data1[respCont].dependents[0].member[memberCont].push(
            {
                id: element.id,
                id_familia: element.id_familia,
                name: element.name,
                surname: element.surname,                
            }
        )
        memberCont++ //adds one to member index
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'resp' of undefined** I dont know what is causing the error, it seems that the property is undefined, but I was not able to find a solution to it. I would appreciate if someone could take a look and help me getting out of this issue.

[image]

Many thanks!

Gines

```js
    const data = [
        {
          "id_familia": 15,
          "relacao": 1,
          "occupation": "RESPONSAVEL",
          "parent_id": null,
          "id": 1547,
          "name": "name resp 1",
          "surname": "surname resp 1",
        },
        {
            "id_familia": 15,
            "relacao": 2,
            "occupation": "DEPENDENTE",
            "parent_id": 15,
            "id": 1548,
            "name": "name dep 1",
            "surname": "surname dep 1",
          },
          {
            "id_familia": 15,
            "relacao": 2,
            "occupation": "DEPENDENTE",
            "parent_id": 15,
            "id": 1548,
            "name": "name dep 2",
            "surname": "surname dep 2",
          },
        {
          "id_familia": 20,
          "relacao": 1,
          "occupation": "RESPONSAVEL",
          "parent_id": null,
          "id": 1178,
          "name": "name resp 2",
          "surname": "PAPARELLA",
        },
        {
          "id_familia": 20,
          "relacao": 1,
          "occupation": "CONJUGE",
          "parent_id": 20,
          "id": 2010,
          "name": "name dep 1",
          "surname": "surname dep 1",
        },
        {
          "id_familia": 20,
          "relacao": 2,
          "occupation": "DEPENDENTE",
          "parent_id": 20,
          "id": 1188,
          "name": "name dep 2",
          "surname": "surname dep 2",
        }
      ]
    
    
    var data1 = [
        {
            resp:{},
            dependents:[
                {
                    member:[],
                    programs:[],
                    activities:[],
                }
            ],
        },
    ] 
    
    var respCont = -1
    var depCont = 0
    
    for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        const element = data[index];
        if(element[index].occupation == "RESPONSAVEL") {
            respCont++ //adds one to resp index
            memberCont = 0
            data1[respCont].resp = {
                id: element.id,
                id_familia: element.id_familia,
                name: element.name,
                surname: element.surname,
            }
        } else {
            data1[respCont].dependents[0].member[memberCont].push(
                {
                    id: element.id,
                    id_familia: element.id_familia,
                    name: element.name,
                    surname: element.surname,                
                }
            )
            memberCont++ //adds one to member index
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this line, you are accessing data1[respCount], but respCount is -1 initially and javascript does not support negative indexing like python. Please modify your code according to your needs. To get an index relatively from ending with respCount having negative values is like `data1.length + respCount`.

```
data1[respCont].dependents[0].member[memberCont].push()
```

Comment: Thank you Siva, but even if I comment the else piece of the code, it does not work. The first iteration goes well, with respCont = 0 it creates data1[0].resp with all values, but when respCont = 1 it throws an error saying that resp is undefined. I really do not know when I messing with it...